# Proving that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln |1 - e^{i\theta}| d\theta = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I found this on some comprehensive exam.

> Prove that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln |1 - e^{i\theta}| d\theta  = 0$.

I was wondering would standard approach work? By that I just mean splitting the integerl up into 
$\int_{-\pi}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\pi}$, and then use $$\ln(1 - e^{i\theta}) = -\sum\frac{e^{i\theta n}}{n}.$$

I found that the first integral yields $-\frac{2}{i n^2}$ and the second yields the negative of that, which yields $0$. But I feel like this is a real-analysis approach.

Can someone give me some insight?

Comment: @Dr.MV, the others probably didn't write that sort because they were probably just trying to finish off what I thought. Thank you though.

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Comment: @Hawk Sorry to be blunt but do you feel the answer you accepted fully answers your question?

Comment: @Did, well it gave me enough to correct myself and is most relevant to my initial query, though lacking one incomplete conclusion.

Comment: @Hawk The whole point of the question is to solve the case $a=1$. How geometric convergence in the case $|a|<1$ can help without further precise argument, escapes me (and no, your initial query is *not* solved in the answer). But if you are happy with it, everything is fine.

Comment: @Did, he just has (okay *I* have to pass the limit). Which according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_theorem is okay.

Comment: The actual proof can be found in http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/mauras/complex-aa1213.pdf (pg 47)

Comment: Sure, there are proofs of these all around. As long as you do not take the accepted answer for a solution (which, at the moment, you may or may not be thinking it is, you are not very clear about that), and although the site is supposed to put together questions and *posts answering them* (not questions and posts not answering them), I guess that everything is fine, in a way. (Anyway, last comment from me on the subject.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $|a|<1$, $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$. You may write
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln(1 - ae^{i\theta}) \:d\theta= -\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n\geq1}a^n\frac{e^{i\theta n}}{n}\:d\theta=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a^n}n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i\theta n}\:d\theta=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a^n}n \times 0=0,
$$ where the termwise integration may be justified by the following uniform bound:
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n} e^{i\theta n}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a|^n }{n}=-\log(1- |a|)<\infty.
$$

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I did…? I thought by rewriting the integrand as a series, we know the sum converges?; sorry but why do we need to work with $(1 - ae^{i\theta})$?

Comment: @Hawk Yes, we have a uniform convergence here, so we are allowed to switch the sum and the integration. Thanks.

Comment: okay, but why is it necessary to still consider $|a| < 1$? What's wrong with leaving that out?

Comment: @Hawk If we leave that, we don't have some justification to permute infinite sum and integration, and we know that it is not always true...

Comment: As it stands, because my series representation is invalid. I supposed letting $a \to 1$ is the finishing step? I am assuming something with continuity justifies the limit equals $0$. I have a lot of trouble getting your name into the comment box for some reason.

Comment: @Hawk Do you agree with my first line in the answer? (to get my name in the comment, starting by typing '@o' in the comment could help).

Comment: Oh I tried "@o" already, it seems to work on the other comment boxes for other people, probably a glitch. I do agree with everything you wrote now. The limit justification, comes from, I believe Fatou's lemma which is missing in the answer.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious or are you computing $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln (1 -a e^{i\theta}) d\theta$$ for every $|a|<1$ instead of $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln |1 - e^{i\theta}| d\theta\ ?$$ The OP and 3 upvoters seem to believe the former implies the latter... On the other hand, you seemed to carefully avoid answering the OP's query about the completeness of your answer so...

Comment: @Did We have
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln|1 - e^{i\theta}| \:d\theta=\frac12\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln\left((1 - \cos \theta)^2+\sin^2\theta\right) \:d\theta=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(2\sin\theta\right) \:d\theta=0,
$$ the last equality being standard.

Comment: I know. (1) Is this computation in your answer? (2) Does this answer the question, starting at "I was wondering"?

Comment: @Did Please, feel free to give another answer to the OP or/and to downvote mine. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I am stunned: is it so difficult to answer the pair of completely basic questions in my comment that you must shift the subject (furthermore, to quite uninteresting subjects, if you ask me, such as votes or whatever)? OK, I guess this is an answer in itself, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Gauss mean value theorem to prove $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln|1 - re^{i\theta}|\, d\theta = 0$ for $0 < r < 1$. Then show that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln|1 - e^{i\theta}|\, d\theta  = \lim\limits_{r\to 1^{-}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln|1 - re^{i\theta}|\, d\theta$.

Comment: So what's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: The first statement is fine, and matches what @Olivier Oloa showed.  But the "then show" part is to me the non-trivial part of this problem -- how do you show that?

Comment: @Hawk you haven't justified the interchange of summation and integral.

Comment: @kobe, I thought it is known that the series (at least in Real Analysis to my memory) converges uniformly.

Comment: @Hawk the greater issue though is that your series representation is invalid. For instance, when $\theta = 0$, your series becomes $-\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n$, which is divergent. It's important to note that the radius of convergence of $\ln(1 - z)$ is $1$, which is why one first works with a discs of radii less than $1$, as suggested by Olivier and myself.

Comment: @kobe, oh sorry you are right. I copied the series from Wikipedia's table, but I totally forgot that little part. $|z| < 1$.

Comment: You can pass the limit through with the dominated convergence theorem. However, it's not clear to me the integrand is analytic.

Comment: I think it is better to differentiate wrt to $r$.

Comment: @naryb it's harmonic, not analytic.

Comment: @naryb there's no need to differentiate.

Comment: $\log(1-x)$ is harmonic but it is not clear to me the integrand is.

Comment: Never mind, I get it! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Cut the complex plane with a line from $(1,0)$ and extending along the positive real axis.

Now, $\log(1-z)$ is analytic within and on a closed contour $C$ defined by $z=e^{i\phi}$ for $\epsilon \le \phi \le 2\pi -\epsilon$, and $z=1+2\sin(\epsilon/2) e^{i\nu}$ for $\pi/2 + \gamma \le \nu \le 3\pi/2 -\gamma$, where $
\cos(\gamma)=\frac{\sin \epsilon}{\sqrt{2(1-\cos \epsilon)}}$ and $0 \le \gamma <2\pi$ on this branch of $\gamma$.

Then, from the residue theorem, we have

$$\int_C  \frac{\log(1-z)}{z}dz=2\pi i \log(1-0)=0$$

which implies

$$\begin{align}
\int_C \frac{\log(1-z)}{z} dz&=\int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} \log(1-e^{i\phi})i d\phi+\int_{3\pi/2-\gamma}^{\pi/2+\gamma} \frac{\log(-2\sin(\epsilon/2) e^{i\nu})}{1+2\sin(\epsilon/2) e^{i\nu}}i2\sin(\epsilon/2) e^{i\nu}d\nu\\\\
&=i\int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} \log(1-e^{i\phi}) d\phi+ i2\sin(\epsilon/2)  \int_{3\pi/2-\gamma}^{\pi/2+\gamma} \frac{\log(-2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\nu})e^{i\nu}d\nu}{1+2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\nu}}   \\\\
&=i\int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} \log|1-e^{i\phi}| d\phi + \int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon} \arctan \left(\frac{\sin \phi}{1-\cos \phi}\right)d\phi \\\\
&+ i2\sin(\epsilon/2)  \int_{3\pi/2-\gamma}^{\pi/2+\gamma} \frac{\log(-2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\nu})e^{i\nu}d\nu}{1+2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\nu}}   \\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

As $\epsilon \to 0$ the first term on the RHS approaches $i$ times the integral of interest.  The second term approaches zero since $\arctan(\frac{\sin \phi}{1-\cos \phi})$ is an odd, periodic function of $\phi$ and the integration extends over the entire period.  And the last term approaches $0$ since $x\log x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.  Thus, the integral of interest is zero!

Comment: This is too creative for me to conjure…but thank you for your contribution.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: How do you get anything analytic out of the absolute value? A non constant real-valued function in the complex plane cannot be analytic.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for the heads up!  I did this problem at 1:00 am.  Found a correct way forward.  Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The integrator is the real-part of the function $z\mapsto\log(1-z)$ restricted to the unit circle. Hence, given $\delta>0$ we can find $\varepsilon>0$ around $z=1$ such that $$-\delta<\int_{-\pi+\varepsilon}^{\pi^-\varepsilon}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta < \delta $$ 
Next, 
$$\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta\sim \varepsilon \log|1-e^{i\theta}| \to 0 \text{ as $\varepsilon \to0$}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $|r|<1$. Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and then $dz=izd\theta$. Note $\ln(1-z)$ is analytic and hence, by Cauchy's Theorem, we have
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln(1 - re^{i\theta}) \:d\theta= \int_{|z|=1}\frac{\ln(1-rz)}{iz}dz=2\pi\ln(1-rz)|_{z=0}=0.
$$ 
Letting $r\to1^-$ and taking the real part give the answer.